# How to use 16 color colorscheme in tty?

Tags: colorscheme, console

I'm trying to use 16 color colorscheme in `vim8.2 1-677` in my `ubuntu18.04` `/dev/tty3`(ctrl-alt-f3).

This is what I have done so far:

Change tty color in my bashrc:

```
if [[ "$TERM" = linux ]]; then
    echo -en "\e]P0282828" #black
    ...
    echo -en "\e]PFebdbb2" #white
    clear
fi
```

execute `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`, pick a small codeset to avoid loosing color bit.

By default, `TERM` is `linux` for tty, the bright foreground is achieved with `bold` attribute:

```
tput bold ; tput setaf 1 ; echo red
```

the bright background is achieved with `blink` attribute:

```
tput blink ; tput setab 1 ; echo red
```

(Check this [page](https://unix-junkie.github.io/christmas/Comparison%20of%20Terminal%20Emulators%20-%20Colour%20Support.html) if your `TERM` is not `linux`)

`:h cterm-colors` says it support the `bold` foreground as bright foreground color, but it won't work for background colors. So I change my `TERM` to `linux-16color`:

```
TERM=linux-16color
infocmp -f linux-16color
-----------
        setab=\E[4
                %p1%{8}%m%d
                %?
                        %p1%{7}%>
                        %t;5
                %e
                        ;25
                %;
                m,
        setaf=\E[3
                %p1%{8}%m%d
                %?
                        %p1%{7}%>
                        %t;1
                %e
                        ;21
                %;
                m,
```

It changed `setaf` and `setab` to use `bold`(1 as on, 21 as off) or `blink`(5 as on, 25 as off) when the color index is greater then 7, check this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/464714/344312) for more explanation.

Then I test 16 foreground and background colors:

```
for ((c = 0; c < 16; c++)); do
printf "|%s%3d%s" "$(tput setaf "$c")" "$c" "$(tput sgr0)"
done
for ((c = 0; c < 16; c++)); do
printf "|%s%3d%s" "$(tput setab "$c")" "$c" "$(tput sgr0)"
done
```

**update**

The color test failed, Foreground 0-7 stop working (I missed that in the original post), they all refer to the 6th foreground color.
[image]

I checked the output sequence:

```
printf "%q\n" $(tput setaf 2)
--------
$'\E[32;21m'
```

The sequence works fine without `21`(bold off), something must be wrong.

Comment: Typically you need to modify your terms colorscheme some to fit their color palette or otherwise indicate 256 v. truecolor

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I think you are talking the first step: `change tty color`.

Comment: I think so too... but to be honest this question could probably use a screenshot or two to show what’s really happening. And you might have better luck talking with the colorscheme maintainers, since they probably see this stuff more often.

Answer (score 5):

### Final result

It should be the same as it's `256color` brother (without bold, underline, italic,...)

### [image]

### Warning

It's not easy, don't do it unless you really want to spend a lot of time in vc(virtual console).

### Setup terminal

Switch to vc, change `TERM`:

```
TERM=linux-16color
```

Some important desription for `linux-16color` from ncurse terminfo, pls read it:

```
# 16-color linux console entry; this works with a 256-character
# console font but bright background colors turn into dim ones when
# you use a 512-character console font. This uses bold for bright
# foreground colors and blink for bright background colors.
...
```

run `sudo dpkg-reconfig console-setup`, choose a small character set(the one starts with `#`) to avoid loosing bright bg color.

Run this script to see if your vc is capable of displaying 16 distinct fg and bg colors:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf "Colors 0 to 15 for the standard 16 foreground colors\n"
for ((c = 0; c < 16; c++)); do
    printf "|%s%3d%s" "$(tput setaf "$c")" "$c" "$(tput sgr0)"
done
printf "|\n\n"

printf "Colors 0 to 15 for the standard 16 background colors\n"
for ((c = 0; c < 16; c++)); do
    printf "|%s%3d%s" "$(tput setab "$c")" "$c" "$(tput sgr0)"
done
printf "|\n\n"
```

There is a good chance you see only 8 distinct fg colors(0-7 are all cyan):
[image]

it's a bug, your `linux-16color` use `21` to clear bold instead of `22`.

```
read !infocmp -f linux-16color | grep -A10 setaf
--------
    setaf=\E[3
        %p1%{8}%m%d
        %?
            %p1%{7}%>
            %t;1
        %e
            ;21  <------------------it's here
        %;
        m,
```

You can see `Parameterized Strings` section of `man terminfo` if you are confucsed by the grammar.

```
man console_codes
--------
...
       21      set normal intensity (ECMA-48 says "doubly underlined")
       22      set normal intensity
...
```

[ncurse terminfo](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-linux-16color) shows history of this bug.

Change 21 to 22, recompile it with tic(If you don't know how to do it, you can copy terminfo from above link to a file and run `tic your_copy`), run the test script again, you should see 16 distinct bg and fg colors.

### Setup tmux (you can skip this if you don't use it)

We must use `screen` family terminfo for tmux, we will try `screen-16color` first, change `TERM`, try above script, you should see only 8 distinct bg colors(n and n+8 is the same):
[image]

Definition of `screen-16color` is:

```
screen-16color|GNU Screen with 16 colors,
        use=ibm+16color, use=screen4,
```

`ibm+16color` use `90-97` and `100-107` ansi SGR code to render bright fg and bg color:

```
        setab=\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t%p1%{40}%+%e%p1%{92}%+%;%dm,
        setaf=\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t%p1%{30}%+%e%p1%{82}%+%;%dm,
```

AFAIK, linux vc doesn't support `100-107` SGR code, `echo -e '\e[101mxxxx'` will only give you normal red bg. To fix it, my first thought is to use `setab` of `linux-16color` directly, but that failed, so I embed the `blink` attribute into the `setab` instead:

```
        setab=\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t25;%p1%{40}%+%e5;%p1%{92}%+%;%dm,
   turn off if < 8 -----------^              ^--------------turn on otherwise
```

I have used it for a few days, it works fine.

### Find or make a suitable colorscheme

It's hard to find a colorscheme for `linux-16color`, lots of colorschemes have this kind of guard:

```
if !(has('termguicolors') && &termguicolors) && !has('gui_running') && &t_Co != 256
  finish
endif
```

There are still some colorscheme in `github` use only 16 ansicolors, but most of of them are degraded version of it's `256color` brother, I don't like it.

I want a color scheme that look exactly like it's `256color` brother (without bold, underline, italic, ...). The best I can find is [solarized](https://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/).

Some extra work need to be done to make `solarized` look exactly the same between `16color` and `256color`.:

```
" ---------------------------------------------------------------------
" ABOUT REVERSE
" ---------------------------------------------------------------------
" linux-16color doesn't have full support for reverse, these commands
" are equal:
"
" tput setaf 1 ; tput setab 10 ; tput rev ; echo 123
" tput setaf 2 ; tput setab 9 ; echo 123
"
" 2 = 10%2, 9 = 1 + 8
"
" bold(1) and blink(5) is used to make fg or bg color brighter(+8), rev works on
" color%8 , bold or blink stays unchanged.
"
" You can only use rev if both fg and bg is greater or less equal to 7. The same
" rule applies to standout, it's better to stay away from them.
...
```

[vim-colors-solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized) has stopped updating for years, so I use my own [fork](https://github.com/dedowsdi/vim-colors-solarized) instead.

Comment: `I want a color scheme that look exactly like it's 256color brother (without bold, underline, italic, ...)` Sort of self-promotion, but [here](https://github.com/matveyt/vim-modest) is my own colorscheme with 8/16/256/truecolor light/dark support. Though I can't claim it has "an exact same" look in all cases.